# How to create a signed URL with limited file size for Google Storage?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to create a signed upload URL so that the client can upload a file directly to a Google Storage bucket and I want to prevent that users upload large files. Therefore, I would like to define the maximum file size that can be uploaded via the signed URL with the official Go SDK. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any examples for that. Is that possible and how would you limit the file size to let's say 1mb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `storage.GenerateSignedPostPolicyV4`, which allows you to set a Policy Document via `PostPolicyV4Options` https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#policy-document

```
storage.GenerateSignedPostPolicyV4("my-bucket", "my-object.txt", &storage.PostPolicyV4Options{
        Conditions: []storage.PostPolicyV4Condition{
            storage.ConditionContentLengthRange(0, 1<<20),
        },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A [policy document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#policy-document) allows to you have a better control on the objects that you are uploading on Cloud Storage, with this feature you can control an array of conditions that every upload must satisfy.

Since you need to control the size of the object you need to upload I suggest you take a look at this example pointed [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#policy-document-example):

```
{"expiration": "2020-06-16T11:11:11Z",
 "conditions": [
  ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
  {"bucket": "travel-maps"},
  {"success_action_redirect": "http://www.example.com/success_notification.html"},
  ["eq", "$Content-Type", "image/jpeg"],
  ["content-length-range", 0, 1000000],
  {"x-goog-algorithm": "GOOG4-RSA-SHA256"},
  {"x-goog-credential": "example_account@example_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com/20191102/auto/storage/goog4_request"},
  {"x-goog-date": "20191102T043530Z"}
  ]
}
```

As you can see the field "content-length-range", 0, 1000000], doesn't allow a document bigger than 1Mb.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `GenerateSignedPostPolicyV4`. This generates a PostPolicyV4 value from bucket, object and opts. The policy allows you to add a file limit as a condition.

```
    pv4, err := storage.GenerateSignedPostPolicyV4("my-bucket", "my-object.txt", &storage.PostPolicyV4Options{
        GoogleAccessID: "my-access-id",
        PrivateKey:     []byte("my-private-key"),

        // The upload expires in 2hours.
        Expires: time.Now().Add(2 * time.Hour),

        Fields: &storage.PolicyV4Fields{
            StatusCodeOnSuccess:    200,
            RedirectToURLOnSuccess: "https://example.org/",
            // It MUST only be a text file.
            ContentType: "text/plain",
        },

        // The conditions that the uploaded file will be expected to conform to.
        Conditions: []storage.PostPolicyV4Condition{
            // Make the file a maximum of 10mB.
            storage.ConditionContentLengthRange(0, 10<<20),
        },
    })
```

You can find more conditions by clicking on [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#policy-document).

After that, you can upload your file using the generated post policy by sending a normal HTTP request.

```
    formBuf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    mw := multipart.NewWriter(formBuf)
    for fieldName, value := range pv4.Fields {
        if err := mw.WriteField(fieldName, value); err != nil {
            // TODO: handle error.
        }
    }
    file := bytes.NewReader(bytes.Repeat([]byte("a"), 100))

    mf, err := mw.CreateFormFile("file", "myfile.txt")
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: handle error.
    }
    if _, err := io.Copy(mf, file); err != nil {
        // TODO: handle error.
    }
    if err := mw.Close(); err != nil {
        // TODO: handle error.
    }

    // Compose the request.
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", pv4.URL, formBuf)
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: handle error.
    }
    // Ensure the Content-Type is derived from the multipart writer.
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", mw.FormDataContentType())
    res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: handle error.
    }
    _ = res
```

The example code can be found [here](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage#GenerateSignedPostPolicyV4)